# How to append string to existing values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary called signames with thousands of key value pairs. A truncated version:

```
signames = {'A_13342_2674_14_': '13342-2674-14.03-0-2-1', 'A_13342_2675_14_': '13342-2675-14.03-0-2-1', 'A_13342_2676_14_': '13342-2676-14.03-0-2-1'}
```

I want to append the character _ to the beginning all values within the python dictionary so that the final dictionary would look like:

```
signames = {'A_13342_2674_14_': '_13342-2674-14.03-0-2-1', 'A_13342_2675_14_': '_13342-2675-14.03-0-2-1', 'A_13342_2676_14_': '_13342-2676-14.03-0-2-1'}
```

My code produces no error but doesn't update the values:

```
for key, value in signames.items():
    key = str(_) + key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `key` variable holds only the value of each key of the dict for each iteration, and if you assign a new value to the key, it only updates that `key` variable, not the dict. You should update the dict itself by referencing the key of the dict in each assignment:

```
for key in signames:
    signames[key] = '_' + signames[key]
```

But as @jpp pointed out in the comment, it would be more idiomatic to iterate over `signames.items()` instead, since the expression in the assignment also involves the value of each key:

```
for key, value in signames.items():
    signames[key] = '_' + value
```

Comment: It's more idiomatic to iterate over `signames.items()`, since your logic involves both key *and* value.

Comment: Thank you-- I understand that explanation!

Comment: @jpp Indeed. Updated as suggested then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do classic dict comprehension here:

```
signames = {k: '_'+ v for k,v in signames.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `key = str(_) + key` since the `signmaes` dictionary is never updated. Just change this line to `signames[key] = '_' + value`.